# Google search with wildcard pattern

Tags: google-search

I want to look up where a house is. Looking out of the window, all I have is a partial sign ending with ..."enrauft".

How would I search with that information in Google?

The wildcard operator only seems to apply to whole words and not parts of a word.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en&ref_topic=3081620) and [an answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Google-search-operator-for-partial-word-search) from Google engineer Jeremy Hoffman, this it not possible:

> No, Google does not have such a feature. It's actually a pretty cool
>   idea, and it would be theoretically possible, but I doubt we'd ever
>   implement such a feature in web search, because
>   1. All features take engineer time to implement and maintain.
>   2. An vanishingly small fraction of Google's billion-plus users would ever want to use it.
>   3. Some users might trigger this behavior unintentionally.
>   4. Simultaneously searching for all terms that could complete a given prefix would take quite significant computational resources. Basically
>   it would slow down several other users' searches.